# Using continue as button for facebook login

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am building a React Native app, I previously implemented Facebook login using login Manager

```
export const onLogin = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
console.log('inside login');
dispatch({ type: ON_LOGIN });
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 
'email']).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
    MakeGraphRequest(dispatch);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    LoginFail(dispatch, error);
  });
 };
 };

 function MakeGraphRequest(dispatch) {
 const responseInfoCallback = (error: ?Object, result: ?Object) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    LoginFail(dispatch, error);
  } else {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'url',
      data: {
        first_name: result.first_name,
        last_name: result.last_name,
        profile_photo: result.picture.data.url,
        email: result.email,
        spend_history: []
      }
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.userid) {
          const userid = res.data.userid;
          LoginSuccessForUnregisteredUser(dispatch, result, userid);
        } else {
          LoginSuccess(dispatch, result);
        }
       });
  }
};
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
'/me',
   {
     parameters: {
         fields: {
                  string: 'email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), birthday'
              }
          }
      },
      responseInfoCallback
  );
  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
}
```

Also I've used Login Button and Expo Facebook login but I could not find a way to implement this kind of a login.

Should I use Login Manager or Login Button. The Facebook docs are valid for web only. Is there a way to integrate this in my RN(react native) project?

[image: This is Facebook login in Grammarly]

Comment: You want a {continue as "SOME-NAME"} button with your facebook login and you are using expo? In this case I would use [AuthSession](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session.html) which makes it really easy to get login with a web browser based authentication flow.

Comment: But would that help me including the user's picture like in the picture, (PS: the blacked out square was a image, sorry for that)

Answer (score 1):

You already have the user data in the response. So you can just start your screen (like in the picture) and ask if the user really wants to sign in with this account. Only after that, call your LoginSuccess events. If the user doesn't want to login just dispose the result data.

```
.then((res) => {
    if (res.data.userid) {
      const userid = res.data.userid;
      // add screen logic here
      // LoginSuccessForUnregisteredUser(dispatch, result, userid);
    } else {
      // add screen logic here
      // LoginSuccess(dispatch, result);
    }
   });
```

Same would go with the [Facebook Login Button](https://snack.expo.io/r1RsVFMYM) or AuthSession.
Using AsyncStorage to save/fetch the state and get wether he goes or goes not to the "continue as" screen.

```
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}

try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    // show "continue as" screen
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Comment: But for that won't the user need to enter details of the facebook account login and password first?

Comment: @DivyeShah I see it like this: when the user wants to login the first time he gets to the normal login screen. When he already logged in sometime then to your "continue as" screen (?). If thats the case just save the userdata e.g. with [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

Comment: Could we fetch user details for facebook login using the app or browser cookies in react native and expo?